# Error Installing PyQt with Qt 4.8.0

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I'm tring to compile/install PyQt 4.9 with Qt 4.8 and Python 3.2. I've installed sip version 4.13.1. But when I run `C:\Python32\python.exe configure.py`. I get the following error:

```
Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 4.9 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 3.2.2 on win32.
Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
Checking to see if the QtGui module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtHelp module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtMultimedia module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtNetwork module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDeclarative module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtOpenGL module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScript module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScriptTools module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSql module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSvg module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtTest module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtWebKit module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXml module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXmlPatterns module should be built...
Checking to see if the phonon module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtAssistant module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDesigner module should be built...
Checking to see if the QAxContainer module should be built...
Qt v4.8.0 free edition is being used.
SIP 4.13.1 is being used.
The Qt header files are in C:\Qt\include.
The shared Qt libraries are in C:\Qt\lib.
The Qt binaries are in C:\Qt\bin.
The Qt mkspecs directory is in C:\Qt.
These PyQt modules will be built: QtCore, QtGui, QtHelp, QtMultimedia,
QtNetwork, QtDeclarative, QtOpenGL, QtScript, QtScriptTools, QtSql, QtSvg,
QtTest, QtWebKit, QtXml, QtXmlPatterns, phonon, QtDesigner, QAxContainer.
The PyQt Python package will be installed in C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages.
PyQt is being built with generated docstrings.
The Designer plugin will be installed in C:\Qt\plugins\designer.
The PyQt .sip files will be installed in C:\Python32\sip\PyQt4.
pyuic4, pyrcc4 and pylupdate4 will be installed in C:\Python32.
Generating the C++ source for the QtCore module...
Creating the Makefile for the QtCore module...
Generating the C++ source for the QtDeclarative module...
sip: __or__() unsupported function return type - provide %MethodCode and a C++ s
ignature
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
```

I've tired reinstalling sip but still no luck. not really sure what's going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you don't need to compile anything - just use the binary installers from the [PyQt4 Download Page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download).

I would suggest you back-out anything you've installed so far and start from scratch. The binary installers include everything you need except for python and the Qt Documentation.